# How to convert a 4D array to two 3D arrays in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have an array which looks like:

```
224×224×3×2 Array{Float32, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 0.117647   0.117647   0.117647   0.117647   …  0.384314  0.396078  0.403922
 0.117647   0.117647   0.117647   0.117647      0.384314  0.392157  0.4
 0.117647   0.117647   0.117647   0.117647      0.384314  0.388235  0.392157
 0.121569   0.117647   0.121569   0.121569      0.388235  0.388235  0.388235
 0.12549    0.117647   0.12549    0.129412      0.396078  0.396078  0.396078
```

which represents a 224x224 image with 3 channels (RGB), but with 2 images. I want to split this apart so that I only have 1 image instead of two per array. How can I take this 4D array and split it?

I will note that the way I got the data in this form is via `imgs = cat(imgs..., dims = 4)` where `imgs` is a 3D array of images with two items, each representing an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `array` is your array then `array[:, :, :, 1]` and `array[:, :, :, 2]` should just work.

If you want an iterator use `eachslice(array, dims=4)` that allows you to iterate slices of the original array along the fourth dimension (this will create views into the original array).